# Apache Maven-2.2.1 failed to download repository

Tags: java, maven

I was using Maven 2.2.1 - successfully downloaded repository on my systems when I had Java 1.6. BUT when I moved to Java 1.7, I am not able to download it again.

NOW I have rollback to java 1.6 but still I am not able to download maven. [NOTE : I HAVE ALSO TRIED IT WITH MAVEN 3.0.3 AND FACING SAME ISSUE]

I am getting following Build Error

System has set JAVA_HOME of Java Home directory

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin:0.4.11:compute-osgi-version': Unable to load the mojo 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin:0.4.11:compute-osgi-version' in the plugin 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin'. A required class is missing: Lorg/apache/maven/shared/osgi/Maven2OsgiConverter;
org.apache.maven.shared.osgi.Maven2OsgiConverter
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionExcep tion: Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin:0.4.11:compute-osgi-version': Unable to load the mojo 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin:0.4.11:compute-osgi-version' in the plugin 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin'. A required class is missing: Lorg/apache/maven/shared/osgi/Maven2OsgiConverter;
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecuto r.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:698)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecuto r.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecuto r.java:556)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecuto r.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecuto r.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExe cutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecuto r.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.jav a:348)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecuto r.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMav en.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven .java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:3 62)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(Co mpatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Nativ e Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Native MethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(De legatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(L auncher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher. java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.ja va:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManagerException: Unable to load the mojo 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin:0.4.11:compute-osgi-version' in the plugin 'com.sun.enterprise:osgiversion-maven-plugin'. A required class is missing: Lorg/apache/maven/shared/osgi/Maven2OsgiConverter;
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getCo nfiguredMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:679)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.execu teMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:468)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecuto r.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/maven/shared/osgi/Maven2OsgiConverter;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.jav a:2291)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1880)
at hidden.org.codehaus.plexus.util.ReflectionUtils.ge tFieldByNameIncludingSuperclasses(ReflectionUtils. java:47)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldCom ponentComposer.getFieldByName(FieldComponentCompos er.java:212)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldCom ponentComposer.findMatchingField(FieldComponentCom poser.java:171)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.FieldCom ponentComposer.assembleComponent(FieldComponentCom poser.java:62)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.DefaultC omponentComposerManager.assembleComponent(DefaultC omponentComposerManager.java:68)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.compose Component(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:1486)
at org.codehaus.plexus.personality.plexus.lifecycle.p hase.CompositionPhase.execute(CompositionPhase.jav a:29)
at org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleHan dler.start(AbstractLifecycleHandler.java:101)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComp onentManager.startComponentLifecycle(AbstractCompo nentManager.java:105)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.AbstractComp onentManager.createComponentInstance(AbstractCompo nentManager.java:95)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.manager.PerLookupCom ponentManager.getComponent(PerLookupComponentManag er.java:48)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup( DefaultPlexusContainer.java:331)
at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup( DefaultPlexusContainer.java:440)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.getCo nfiguredMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:652)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.shared.osgi.Maven2OsgiConverter
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java: 200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.j ava:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:3 07)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClas sDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadCla ss(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadCla ss(DefaultClassRealm.java:274)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClas s(RealmClassLoader.java:214)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:2 52)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoade r.java:320)
... 36 more
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 29 minutes 36 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Dec 21 13:07:49 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/23M
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can anybody please let me know what settings are changed that I need to update ?

Thanks

Comment: CAn you post the full log output? But i would suggest to clean your local repository and retry.

Comment: could it be that your installation is corrupted?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am clearing ".m2" (situated at my user) folder every-time whenever I restart downloading it. Anything else needed to clear? The complete log output is - http://neelamsharma.s3.amazonaws.com/Maven_Result-2.2.1.txt

Comment: Have you taken a deep look into the output: Things like this there are many messages like 
[DEBUG] attempting to create parent directories for destination: maven-osgi-0.2.0.jar.tmp
185/185b
185b downloaded  (maven-osgi-0.2.0.jar)
[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '6c9fd3d150b8a5f0ca676f49b8ed603793cabebb'; remote = '<html>
<head><title>301' - RETRYING and the html part show there is something wrong with your repository access (firewall, proxy ?)

Comment: @khmarbaise I am running with default settings. In setting.xml file these tags are commented <proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>proxypass</password>
      <host>proxy.host.net</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    -->
  </proxies> Can you suggest me where to make changes to get rid from this error?

Comment: From where did you taken the settings.xml file? Have you changed it?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have downloaded Maven 2.2.1 bin (apache-maven-2.2.1-bin) from apache site http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi, nothing changes I have made in any file and in myfolder\apache-maven-2.2.1\conf\settings.xml

Comment: Than you have other problems. May be sitting behind a proxy? Why did you downloaded such an old version and not 3.0.4 ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22100/discussion-between-neelam-sharma-and-khmarbaise)